# How can I use Google Analytics in a Java program

Tags: java, google-analytics

What I need to do is log clicks and etc and log them in google analytics in a java program. I have done lots of googling, but have found nothing. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of the Google Analytics Measurement Protocol in Java.  It has support for a subset of the parameters.  If it's missing something you need, go ahead and open a feature request issues.

> https://github.com/akoscz/GoogleAnalytics

Contributions and Pull Requests are always welcome!